# Make exceptions be thrown

Tags: java, testing, exception

How can I make java throw an IOexception as well as an InterruptedException? So far for an IO exception I made a file have no read/write/execute permissions but that did not work. I am not sure how else I can make an IO exception be thrown.

Comment: `throw new IOException("That wasn't so hard.");`

Comment: @Dici yes it is. Sorry that didnt pop up when I entered my question or looked on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the `java.io` classes documentation, the reasons why some methods throw an `IOException` are detailed. You can also simply instantiate an `IOException` and throw it...

```
throw new IOException("Some error message");
```

As for the `InterruptedException`, you can do this by interrupting a Thread running a inifinite loop (for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
throw new IOException("Text");
```

You can use `google`

Comment: I did use google and it didnt give me an answer